# Несоответствие типов в java

Tags: массивы, типы-данных, eclipse, java

В моей программе есть следующие объявления массивов

```
ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();//этот массив в дальнейшем заполняется с помощью метода add
String[] ConcatPaths= new String[CountComputers];
if (paths.size()%CountComputers==0)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<CountComputers; i++)
        {
            ConcatPaths[i]=paths[NumberOfElementConcatPaths];

        }
    }
```

При вводе строки в eclipse

```
ConcatPaths[i]=paths[NumberOfElementConcatPaths];
```

отображает всплывающую подсказку

```
The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList<String>
```

Я новичок в Java, поэтому просьба отнестись с пониманием. Какие мне надо объявить массивы, чтоб использовать динамический массив строк и обычный массив строк?

Comment: лучше испольсовать коллекции мар интерфейса

Comment: а зачем ему мап, если нужно хранить не пары ключ-значение, а набор значений одного типа?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это массив

```
ConcatPaths
```

А это список

```
paths
```

К элементам списка нужно обращаться через метод `.get`, т.е.

```
ConcatPaths[i] = paths.get(NumberOfElementConcatPaths);
```